# CSS animations not working on all React components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm working on a dashboard app that takes company data from various sources and presents this on some animated "tiles" in a React app. The app will dynamically redirect to different pages showing data from different areas of the business after a timeout. This is all working as expected, but the animation is being lost on some of these tiles.

After a bit of investigation, I've sussed that the number of tiles that don't have the animation is always equal to the number of tiles showing on the previous page (i.e. my second page currently has 4 tiles, so after redirecting the first 4 tiles on the next page to do animate), so there must be some kind of connection here.

This is the Dashboard class, which constructs the whole thing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import { GridList, GridListTile } from "@material-ui/core"

import "../assets/scss/tile.scss"
import Request from "../config.json"
import DataTile from "./DiagnosticDataTile"
import Loader from "./Loader"
import { IDiagnosticResultData } from "../interfaces/IDiagnosticResultData"
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router"

interface IPropsPassed {
  category: string
  redirect: string
}

type IProps = IPropsPassed & RouteComponentProps

interface IState {
  result: IDiagnosticResultData[]
  pageWillChange: boolean
  loading: boolean
}

class Dashboard extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  maxTilesPerRow = 4
  changeTimeInMinutes = 5

  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      result: null,
      pageWillChange: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    axios
      .get(Request.url)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ result: response.data })
        this.setState({ loading: false })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }

  GetCellHeight(data: IDiagnosticResultData[]): number {
    return window.innerHeight / Math.ceil(data.length / this.maxTilesPerRow)
  }

  GetColour(isOk: boolean): string {
    const purples = ["#7e4c84", "#68396c", "#744177", "#78477f"]

    return isOk ? this.Sample(purples) : "#cd1010"
  }

  Sample(colour: string[]): string {
    return colour[Math.floor(Math.random() * colour.length)]
  }

  NoOfColumns(data: IDiagnosticResultData[]): number {
    return Math.min(data.length, this.maxTilesPerRow)
  }

  changePageAfter(minutes: number): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.replace(this.props.redirect)
    }, minutes * 60000)
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props) { return null }

    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Loader />
    } else {
      var data = this.state.result.filter(x =>
        x.categories.includes(this.props.category)
      )
      this.changePageAfter(this.changeTimeInMinutes)
      return (
        <GridList
          cols={this.NoOfColumns(data)}
          cellHeight={this.GetCellHeight(data)}
          className="tileList"
        >
          {data.map((object, i) => (
            <GridListTile
              key={i}
              className="tile"
              style={{
                animationDuration: `${Math.random() * 2 + 1}s`,
                background: `${this.GetColour(object.status === "OK")}`
              }}
            >
              <DataTile data={object} />
            </GridListTile>
          ))}
        </GridList>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard)
```

Apologies if this description is too vague. If any more info is required I'll try to specify more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `key` prop at `<GridListTile />` is not unique.

I've build a simple [app here](https://jsfiddle.net/jnavm386/) where the key is unique and the [same where the keys are not unique](https://jsfiddle.net/jnavm386/1/) (see line 25).

The animations are working only on new html elements. If the key is unique react handles it as a new html object.